# A continuous map with group action

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $X, Y$ be two topological spaces. If group $G$ acts on $X$ and $f:X\to Y$ is a $G$-invariant continuous map,i.e., $f\circ g=f$, why does it induce a homeomorphism between the quotient space of $X$ by $G$ and $Y$, that is,

$$X/G\cong Y ?$$

Could you give me some help with details？ Thanks a lot.

Comment: The domain $X/G$ and range $Y$ being not groups but topological spaces, I presume you mean not "homomorphism" but "homeomorphism" instead?

Comment: Yes, homeomorphism, how to prove it?@LeeMosher

Comment: if the action is good, i.e., the action is effective and the group is a  finite group, the conclusion holds?@freakish If so, how to prove it?

Comment: Why does it hold in the definition of orbifolds?@freakish

Answer (score 1):

This obviously cannot be true when $f$ is not surjective. But even if it is, it still isn't true.

Consider the singleton $Y=\{*\}$. Then any $f:X\to Y$ (and by "any" I mean the single possible choice) is $G$-invariant, regardless of what $X$, $G$ and the action are. And so, if $G$ doesn't act transitively on $X$ (i.e. $X/G$ has at least two elements), then $X/G$ cannot be homeomorphic to $Y$.

Another counterexample is $Y=X/G$ but we put a coarser, non-homeomorphic topology on $Y$. In particular if $X/G$ is not anti-discrete, then we can consider $Y=X/G$ with antidiscrete topology. Then the projection $f:X\to Y$ provides a counterexample.

You've mentioned in the comments orbifolds. In orbifolds it is **assumed** that the induced map
$$X/G\to Y$$
$$[x]\mapsto f(x)$$
is a homeomorphism. It is an additional condition and it doesn't follow from other conditions.